# Google Apps Script, Gmail UI Add-on, how to remove Cc Recipients?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, gmail, google-workspace-add-ons

*My very first question... :)*

In Gmail UI Add-on, I want to remove cc recipient:

```
function onGmailCompose(e) {
  var buttonSet = CardService.newButtonSet()
      
      .addButton(CardService.newTextButton().setText('Example Button')
                  .setOnClickAction(CardService.newAction().setFunctionName('ButtonAction'))
                  .setTextButtonStyle(CardService.TextButtonStyle.FILLED));

  var card = CardService.newCardBuilder()
      .setHeader(CardService.newCardHeader().setTitle('Choose...'))
      .addSection(CardService.newCardSection().addWidget(buttonSet));
  
  return card.build();
}

function ButtonAction(e) {
  Logger.log(e);

  var response = CardService.newUpdateDraftActionResponseBuilder()
        .setUpdateDraftCcRecipientsAction(CardService
            //this works fine
            .newUpdateDraftCcRecipientsAction().addUpdateCcRecipients(['jon.doe@example.com']));
            
            //but how to clear CcRecipients?

            //this doesn't work.
            //.newUpdateDraftCcRecipientsAction().addUpdateCcRecipients([]));

            //neither this.
            //.newUpdateDraftCcRecipientsAction().addUpdateCcRecipients());

            //neither this.
            //.newUpdateDraftCcRecipientsAction().addUpdateCcRecipients(['']));

  return response.build();
}
```

documentation is not much of a help:

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/card-service/update-draft-cc-recipients-action

Any ideas?

Comment: I don't understand what you are doing.  Are trying to edit in compose mode or are you trying to change emails that you've received.  The card service is not real flexible and most complex interactions have to be handle via apps script.

Comment: The goal is to edit in compose mode via card service. It isn't too flexible indeed. However I think my demands are not so complicated: while replaying to some email I want to remove any cc/bcc with one click...

Comment: I'm pretty sure the card service was meant to be that way so there wouldn't be any holes that would allow developers to mess with the gmail ui in any way.

Comment: So it looks I have to change my approach here...

Comment: Oh there is. You can change subject, recipients and body of your email. There is no way to  CLEAR recipients. Here you have an example: https://developers.google.com/workspace/add-ons/cats-quickstart